# How do I draw the domain of $z = \sqrt{\sin\pi(x^2+y^2)} $ on the $xOy$ plane

Tags: calculus

**Question**

> How do I draw the domain of $z = \sqrt{\sin\pi(x^2+y^2)} $ on the $xOy$ plane

Since $\sin(\pi(x^2 + y^2))$ must produce a value between $-1$ and $1$, and the square root function is only defined for non-negative values, we need to find the $x$ and $y$ values for which $\sin(\pi(x^2 + y^2))$ is non-negative which implies that $\sin(π(x^2 + y^2)) \geq 0$

The sine function is non-negative for angles in the range $[0, \pi]$ and $[2n\pi, (2n+1)\pi]$, where $n$ is an integer. Therefore, we have:

$$0 \leq \pi(x^2 + y^2) ≤ \pi \quad \textrm{and} \quad 2n\pi ≤ \pi(x^2 + y^2) \leq (2n+1)\pi$$

Dividing by $\pi$ gives:

$$0 ≤ x^2 + y^2 ≤ 1 \quad \textrm{and} \quad 2n \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 2n+1$$

These inequalities define a series of concentric annular regions in the $xy$-plane, starting with a circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin and then alternating between excluded and included regions as $x^2 + y^2$ increases.
In summary, the domain of the function is a union of an infinite series of annular regions in the $xy$-plane.

But how do I draw the domain of  $z = \sqrt{\sin\pi(x^2+y^2)} $ on the xOy plane?

Comment: You have described the domain so clearly that I am having a difficult time seeing what is stopping you from just drawing the shapes you described. So far I have thought of only two possibilities: 1. You got the wording "concentric annular regions" from somewhere but you don't know what it means; 2. You know what concentric annular regions are but don't see how to compute their inner and outer radii other than the circle of radius $1.$ Is there a third possibility I haven't thought of?

Comment: Unfortunately, my computer is so obsolete I can't make a drawing in any appropriate application, so I would be happy if somebody can make it for me:)

Comment: Perhaps this is what you need: https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: not really, I need something like this https://i.imgur.com/eFAhDB0.png but in a top view, desmos can't do that(

Comment: Desmos can draw an annulus, which is what you said you needed. I'm assuming you don't want to just sketch the regions on paper with a pencil, but maybe you could do that just for this question, which then becomes "how can I draw this figure better?" (And explain what it is about the hand drawing that needs to be improved upon.)

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I can't draw it in desmos, I just get a straight line instead of annulus:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145105/discussion-between-lokey8573-and-david-k).

Answer (score 2):

To draw the domain of $z = \sqrt{\sin(\pi(x^2+y^2))}$ on the $xOy$ plane, we can plot the boundaries of the annular regions found in the previous step. The domain consists of all points in the $xy$-plane that satisfy the inequality $0 ≤ x^2 + y^2 ≤ 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 2n$ for some integer $n$.

Starting from the origin, we can draw the first boundary as a circle of radius $1$. The next boundary is a circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$, followed by a circle of radius $\sqrt{4}$, and so on, with each subsequent circle having a radius equal to the square root of the next integer multiple of $2$.

To show that the annular regions alternate between excluded and included, we can shade every other region or use different colors for each region.

Comment: This part is not true (not properly formulated):   
Note that the domain of the function does not include the points outside the circles of radius $\sqrt{2n},$ since for those points, $\sin\pi(x^2+y^2)$
 is negative and the square root is undefined.

Comment: You started out well with a circle of radius $\sqrt1,$ then $\sqrt2,$ but you skipped the circle of radius $\sqrt3.$

Comment: Could you please make a drawing for me and attach a link or something ?)